# I just want to understand how these two codes work

Tags: java

I have two code that I do not understand and if anyone could explain to me the process of how they are working.  The first one prints a pyramid out of stars and the second prints this:

```
a b c d e 
a b c d 
a b c 
a b 
a
```

I compiled both codes but I just cannot understand how it works.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 5 - i; k++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        for (int k = 0; k <= 2 * i; k++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < 5 - i; j++)
            System.out.print((char) ('a' + j) + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

No error messages; I just want to understand the process

Comment: watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YseitO6gTwE

Comment: how does the for-statement work?

Comment: Which part do you not understand? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
// outer loop to handle number of rows 
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
    {
//  inner loop to handle number of columns 
            //  values changing acc. to outer loop    
        for (int j=0; j < 5 - i; j++)
//prints the each charcter after 'a'
            System.out.print((char) ('a' + j) + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```